# Pastes text from the clipboard in one tap into the edittext application

Tags: android, clipboard

I'm building a simple application like a floating clipboard that can copy text from other applications and paste it into my application.

What I need now is can I paste the text already saved in the listview with one click into another application (example: myblogger), just like the keyboard pastes the selected text clipboard on another application's text edit field like the following picture

[image: Sample]

I want the list of items that I click directly attached to the blogger EditText.

Can anyone help me here? Because I'm too new to Android coding.

So far I've only relied on Googling to build my simple apps and I've never asked before.

Therefore, anyone who answers my question, whether it is useful for me or not, I am very grateful.

Comment: Is the clipboard part of your current app? It is some other app of yours? Or is it the system clipboard?